# Rotate an image in Angular 9

Tags: html, angular, web, rotation

I need to rotate an image in html from my component with

```
(document.querySelector('#image') as HTMLElement).style.transform = `rotate(${degree}deg)`;
```

or

```
document.getElementById('#image').style.transform = `rotate(${degree}deg)`;
```

and set an id to it here

```
<img id= "image" class="arrow" src = "assets/arrow.png"/>
```

but it crashes the page with this error

> core.js:5882 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: How about adding a class  whenever you need to rotate the element? class is predefined with rotate styles.  Is it fulfill your requirement?

Comment: @SandyB the problem is i need to calculate the angle then update the image rotation inside the constructor of the component but it crashes

Comment: How about  a stackblitz? Any chance you can set it up for reproducing the issue

Comment: @SandyB i'm asking is the above code is correct or not ? i searched a lot it's strange how there is no someone to know the problem the image exists inside the html and it do rotate when i set the style inside the html but can't from the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference it without a hash symbol and use `renderer2` to edit styles/classes.

For details please check my [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cavcg4), this are the main changes:

```
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const degree = 90;
    const image = document.getElementById('image');
    this.renderer.setStyle(
      image,
      'transform',
      `rotate(${degree}deg)`
    )
  }
```

Comment: @sheko you have to import it from ```@angular/core``` Here is a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cavcg4

Comment: @sheko please take a look at the stackblitz, it is working...